# Hamcrest and Mockk for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I am trying to write tests in the `shared` module of a [KMM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/add-dependencies.html) project. In the shared module's build.gradle.kts file I have the following:

```
sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting
    val commonTest by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
            implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))


            //TODO: Hamcrest
            //implementation("junit:junit:4.12")
            //implementation("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3")

            //TODO: Mockk
            //implementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.10.4")
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

I have also tried:

```
implementation(kotlin("[library]"))
```

with the same result: The tests are no longer recognised by the IDE and I cannot run them.

Comment: I think either hamcrest and mockk [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65491916/mock-common-tests-in-kotlin-using-multiplatform) are not kotlin multiplatform libraries.

Comment: Oh dear I thought the ones in test could at least be standard kotlin libs since they don't get deployed... I see the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320492/kotlin-multiplatform-how-to-mock-objects-in-a-unit-test-for-ios thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a mocking library that has K/N support (AFAIK).

Here's [Mockk's K/N](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/58) and [Mockk's K/JS](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/projects/2#card-16016754) issue for future reference or you could also check out [Touchlab's Karmok](https://github.com/touchlab/Karmok)

For Hamcrest, see their issue [here](https://github.com/npryce/hamkrest/issues/58)

**Edit/Update**

In 2022 above answer doesn't stand true anymore. [Mockk](https://mockk.io/) now supports mocking in shared modules. Please check here [mockk.io](https://mockk.io/) Add the following dependency and you should be good to go

`testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-common:{version}"`

The mocking experience is seamless, just like a regular Android unit test case.

Answer (score 1):

I got a response from the KMM team - thought I would put it here for reference

> You can use only multiplatform dependencies that support all declared targets in common source-set, because this could will be used for compilation for all the targets. Junit is not a multiplatform library, it’s JVM, so you should add it to your jvm target source-set (androidMain if you declared android() target). Check this project: https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-sample/blob/master/shared/build.gradle.kts for example.
> The same issue relates to other dependencies - they are not multiplatform, so you can’t use them in a commons source-set.

Answer (score 0):

Most mocking libraries are currently JVM-only - *mockk* and *hamcrest*, too.

There are some Kotlin multiplatform mocking libraries using KSP-based code generation with somewhat limited mocking support, but compatible with Kotlin/Native as well:

- https://github.com/kosi-libs/MocKMP
- https://github.com/mockative/mockative